# How to get the resolved network of kafka inside docker?

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka

I have a spring application, which should connect to the kafka. This is what my Docker file looks for spring application:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-11 as builder
# create app folder for sources
RUN mkdir -p /build
WORKDIR /build
COPY pom.xml /build
#Download all required dependencies into one layer
RUN mvn -B dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugins
#Copy source code
COPY src /build/src
# Build application
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The kafka/Postgres/zookeeper everything other, comes from Docker images. So thought will run the application in docker compose, so that it looks like the following:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    postgres:
        image: debezium/postgres
        environment:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: qwerty
          POSTGRES_USER: appuser
        volumes:
           - ./postgres:/data/postgres
        ports:
          - 6532:6532
    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
        ports:
          - "2181:2181"
        environment:
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
          - postgres
        ports:
          - "9092:9092"
        environment:
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
          KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          KAFKA_LOG_CLEANER_DELETE_RETENTION_MS: 5000
          KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
          KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: 1
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
    connector:
        image: debezium/connect:latest
        ports:
          - "8083:8083"
        environment:
          GROUP_ID: 1
          CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
          OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
          BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
          - postgres
          - kafka
    app-server:
    # Configuration for building the docker image for the backend service
        build:
          context: . # Use an image built from the specified dockerfile in the `polling-app-server` directory.
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "8080:8080" # Forward the exposed port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host machine
        restart: always
        depends_on: 
          - kafka 
          - zookeeper
          - postgres
          - connector
        environment:
          BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
```

I pass an environment variable `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` with value as `kafka:9092` (since `localhost:9092` doesn't work inside my docker environment).

And in my spring code, I get the value like the following:

```
System.getenv("bootstrap.servers")
// or
System.getenv("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS")
```

however, when I run `docker-compose up`, I get the value as `null` for the above Java code. Not sure, what is the best way to get the docker resolved network for my kafka.

So how to fix it so that java code picks up the Kafka broker inside the docker environment?

Comment: Why not `System.getenv("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS")`, the actual name of the var?

Comment: I tried the same.. But it didn't work out.

Comment: @Ant's Did u point kafka to localhost in etc/hosts file ? What have u done there ?

Comment: Do we need to change in `/etc/host` ? This is running inside a docker right?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what your question is. Are you asking how to write Java code to look up an environment variable? Or your Java code is failing to connect to the Kafka broker? or what?

Comment: Java code is not picking up the Kafka broker inside the docker. So how to fix it?

Comment: You need to show us a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: Actually: if you run all the images with docker-compose, you dont need this environment definition. Docker-compose will run up a docker network for you. And just calling 'kafka' (which is the name of the service) inside your code should work

Comment: Another obvious thing is that your environment definition should be writent with "=" and not  ":" so BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092 this should solve the problem of null

Comment: You don’t need to define environment variable to access service from one container to another. You can access directly using the service name. And for docker compose you even don’t need to define network, by default docker compose defines a network and enables all the services under the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Here is *some suggestions* that might not give you a complete solution (and your problem might be from another place, or another system issue) but  might also help you :

I) **Minors fix and improvments of the docker-compose file**

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) you can use either a **dictionary** *or* a **list** to define the environment param. In your case, you decided to use a dictionary but maybe you could try to use a list here (or an `.env` file as i explained bellow) for that :

1) you should add a "-" at the begining of each new defiinition

2) You should use equals sign (not column)

3) **and last but not least**: since your variable includes special characters (the column for the port) you should escape all the definition with quotes :

```
    environment:
       - 'BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092'
```

Now if you really want to use a dictionary notation, you still need to escape the column ("kafka:9092") otherwise this could be interpreted (by the YAML parser) as a new nested dictionary ([see here example of host connections strings](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts))

so :

```
environment:
   BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:9092'
```

But the best practice is to use a `.env` file, its content is very simple :

`BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092`

And then remove your `environment` definition from your docker-compose and pass this option :

```
env_file:
  - ./<name_of_your_env_file>.env
```

Now just keep in mind that there is a priority in environment definition if you decide to use both `.env` file, `environment` and `shell` variable (for example) [(See here)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file).

> 1. Compose file
> 2. Shell environment variables
> 3. Environment file
> 4. Dockerfile
> 5. Variable is not defined

II) **Tomcat default embedded server**

Another thing I found :

since you are using Spring : its default embedded server is a Tomcat (unless you changed it in your dependencies) . 
From an AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html) (even if you don't use it, it could lead you to a solution) :

> the Java SE platform sets environment variables that you
>   retrieve with System.getenv, while **the Tomcat platform sets Java
>   system properties that you retrieve with System.getProperty**.

So maybe try :

```
System.getProperty("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS")
```

III) **No need to define this environment variable at all** :

The last thing (as I said in question's comments) : when you work with docker-compose, a **docker network** is build for you by this tool.

Each container can be reached by calling its service name that you give in the yaml file.

So in your code, you just need to call the "kafka" service.

Now if you use an environment variable, of course, it provides you some flexibility to inject different services name to test with (let say tomorrow you want to use NATS or RabbitMQ you'll be able to just change the dependency by changing the environment variable) but as a first step maybe you could try to call "kafka" service directly and see if it gets connected : in this way you'll eliminate this possibility...